# react redux -- `state.function[item]` syntax

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to grok Redux's async [Reddit API example code](https://redux.js.org/advanced/example-reddit-api)

But I'm having a really hard time understanding what's going on with these two functions:

```
//action
function shouldFetchPosts(state, subreddit) {
  const posts = state.postsBySubreddit[subreddit]
  if (!posts) {
    return true
  } else if (posts.isFetching) {
    return false
  } else {
    return posts.didInvalidate
  }
}

//reducer 
function postsBySubreddit(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In particuar, `postsbySubreddit[subreddit]`; I've never seen a function accessed with subscript notation, and doesn't that function require a parameter when it's called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state.postsBySubreddit` is not a function, it's the name of the attribute in the store where the `postsBySubreddit` reducer function stores it's state.

If you had a system with 3 reducers, `r1()`, `r2()` and `r3()` then the `store` would have 3 attributes where these reducers store their data: `store.r1`, `store.r2` and `store.r3`.

Comment: Ahh I see, and the state of those attributes corresponds to the output of those functions I take it?